# Wordpress Multipage Variable in the_content Filter

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add a filter to my Wordpress functions.php file and I am running into an issues with the `$multipage` global variable.

I am assuming that the variable has not been defined yet within the_content, because I am trying to add a filter to the_content, and the `$multipage` variable seems to be empty.

```
function the_content_filter( $content ) {
    global $multipage;
    if ( $multipage ) {
        return 'multipage is true';
    } else {
        return 'multipage is false';
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'the_content_filter' );
```

always returns 'multipage is false'. It seemse $multipage is an empty string. This is the case on both multipage, and single-page posts.

How do I determine if the post is single or multipage within my the_content filter if I cannot use the global $multipage variable?

Answer (score 1):

`add_filter` doesn't work like that. It won't `echo` out your content. You need to `return` a value. Also, `$multipage` is a boolean, meaning it only returns TRUE or FALSE.

You can try this:

```
function the_content_filter( $content ) {
    global $multipage;

    /* This will tell you if it's a multipage. It will display int(0) if it's not or int(1) if it is. Remove this line when you are done testing. */
    var_dump( $multipage );

    if ( $multipage ) {
        return 'multipage is true';
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'the_content_filter' );
```

This will display `multipage is true` instead of the content if `$multipage` is true, otherwise it will display the original content.

Here's documentation on `the_content` filter: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/

Comment: Except it will echo stuff out. And this doesn't work for me. In both cases it returns the content.

Comment: What is it `echoing`? You updated your question after I posted my answer with `returns`. Also, it appears that `$multipage` only works within the `loop`. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66648/how-to-access-global-multipage-or-global-numpages-outside-the-loop

Comment: I did update in case someone else thought that would be the issue. When I had it echoing it echoed just a blank string in both cases. I saw that wordpress said that but I also don't really know what "in the loop" means. I was also hoping that there would be a way around it. I need to change the content on a page differently for single and multi page articles, so I was hoping to get some help finding another way to do this.

Comment: `In the loop` means, that the variable will only be set in your `while` loop for the posts. `if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();` Also, the link I provided in my comment should be able to help you.

Comment: @LucyTurtle try what I have with the `var_dump` added. You should see `int(0)` directly above the content of your post. If you don't that means it's a multipage post.

Comment: Actually that link that you sent in your comment is exactly what I needed! When I var_dump ed I got 'bool(false)' for both types. But that link was perfect!